# From Address Shows NetworkCredential User Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have made an web application for sending e-mail. It works fine.

The problem is receiver end - Receiver shows NetworkCredential User Email as From Email.
And the email provided as From Email doesn't exist.

i want to show the suplied email not the networkcredential user email to the receiver.

sample code-

```
using System.Net.Mail;


MailMessage oMsg = new MailMessage();
oMsg.From = new MailAddress("sender@somewhere.com","Diplay Name");
oMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@somewhere.com")); 
oMsg.Subject = "Send Using Web Mail";
oMsg.Body ="Hi..";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient s = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("host", port_no);
System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
s.EnableSsl = true;
s.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
s.Credentials = nc;
s.Send(oMsg);
```

The receiver gets from email is "user" but i want to show "sender@somewhere.com".

Comment: That means there is a problem at **All set well** & works fine, if the from address is not able to authenticate then it would use the credentials passed, is it so or did i miss something

Comment: i m not able to understand you, can you ask in simple english...

Comment: Maybe you need to check the settings, it may not allow be allowing a id which is not in the domain and hence using the credentials id to sent the mail

Comment: there is no setting for that..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the Display name of the e-mail address that you send from.

Update oMsg.From = new MailAddress("sender@somewhere.com"); to be oMsg.From = new MailAddress("sender@somewhere.com","sender@somewhere.com");

Comment: So change it to be oMsg.From = new MailAddress("sender@somewhere.com","Your required display name");

Answer (score 0):

MailAddress has an overload which allows you to pass is a display name for the given mail addres e.g. `new MailAddress("sender@somewhere.com", "Display Name");`

Answer (score 0):

Some mail services (such as google), override the .FROM value, and will always use the ENVELOPE value, which is the NetworkCredential username.

I have a feeling that is what you are seeing.